# Separate domain for vendor storefront in cs-cart

Tags: redirect, cs-cart, storefront

I have a main storefront built in cs-cart multivendor edition with domain name abc.com. I wanted to have separate domain urls for each vendors, such that

1. abc.com/vendorA would redirect to the domain url of vendorA, vendorA.com
2. abc.com/vendorB would redirect to the domain url of vendorB, vendorB.com, and so on....

How can I achieve this in cs-cart multivendor?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed my own multidomain and multi-subdomain addons on cs-cart multi-vendor system. it took me very very long time to fugure it out a solution for the needs.

From your question, I can see you are new for the CS-CART Multi-Vendor. because you don't know what you are asking or asking your question only in half.

are you asking only redirect abc.com/vendorA to VendorA.com OR are you looking to host the VendorA.com on the same your multi-vendor application?

if you are asking only redirect abc.com/vendorA to their vendorA.com, then the visitor who clicked the link will out from your website and go to their website. you can do it with url_post hook and on the hook you can get their url from db and with condition redirect them to vendorA.com. in this case you have to force your vendors to put their url at registration or companies.update.

but if you are asking to host vendor's websites on the same application, then it's very very long story. Also there will be a lots of questions for you before to say anything or answer it correctly.

Comment: Hi Mem, thank you for your answer.

I am new to cs-cart multivendor. you answered my question. I was asking to only redirect abc.com/vendorA to their domain vendorA.com. I will follow as you suggested.

and another question related to this is, I tried redirecting from cs-cart to external. The problem is, vendorA.com is in iframe for abc.com/vendorA and when redirecting externally I am in an infinite loop. Can you suggest a method to redirect externally, in a website that is loaded in iframe.

THank you!

Comment: I don't know how you are using IFRAME, so I can't answer anything. but if you are NOT hosting vendorA.com on the same application, then after URL_POST it has to show external URL on cs-cart pages, isn't? just watch the URL_POST HOOK and it's purpose more deeply, you will see it. it's original url is like this; companies.products?company_id= and the the link parts array. but they gets url objects from seo_names table. keep digging more deeply.